# How to determine identity of missing LocalDB instance?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a small Web API app that runs fine under Visual Studio.  When I try to deploy it under IIS, however, I get this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. )

The app is using a sqllocaldb server, and the server is started and queries (via `sqllocaldb info`) as being alive and running.  I have tried setting the app pool `Identity` to my userid vs using "ApplicationPoolIdentity", and have tried setting up and using a shared version of the server.  Changing the userid produced a different but equally unhelpful message; using a shared server changed nothing.

I've also determined that I can provoke the same message running directly in VS if I use a bogus server instance name in the connection string.

It would be ever so slightly helpful if the error message positively identified *which* server instance it cannot find, but nowhere in the message (either in the browser or when examined by an attached Visual Studio session) does it name the missing server.

How can one identify the "does not exist" server?

**Update:**

A coworker solved my problem (without actually answering the above question).  The solution was to open my applicationHost.config file (In Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) and edit the `<system.applicationHost> <applicationPools> <add>` item for the application pool containing my app and add (within the `<processModel>` element) `loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true"`.  Exactly what that hocus pocus does I don't know, but he found it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx).